# What is the best way to add Error Bars to my graph?

Tags: r, sql-server, ggplot2

Below is the code I used to create my bar graph without the Error Bars. How can I best add in error bars.  Do I need to use `geom_errorbars` and if so how do I format this with how my data frame for this graph is formatted(in picture)[My data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHAHl.png)?

```
ggplot(BrainPursuitsScore, aes(x = Conditions, y = Average_Score)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "Blue") + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 5)) + 
ggtitle("Brain Pursuits Score") + 
xlab("Group Name") + ylab("Average Score") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5))
```

Comment: I have since realized I was using the wrong data frame to visualize what I was looking for.  I went back to my original code creating my data frame and added in a column with a sd for each row which I named sd.  From there I was able to easily add geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average_Score-sd, ymax=Average_Score+sd)) to my graph code and it worked like a charm.

Thanks yall for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options `ggplot2` and `geom_errorbar` or the `errbar` function from Frank Harrell's `Hmisc`. Regardess of what you choose, you need to compute the locations of the centres and endpoints yourself.

I can't be bothered replicating your data, so here is an example using a built-in dataset.

```r
data(warpbreaks)

library(dplyr)
wb.summary = warpbreaks %>% 
  group_by(wool,tension) %>% 
  summarise(m = mean(breaks), 
            lb = mean(breaks) - 2 * sd(breaks), 
            ub = mean(breaks) + 2 * sd(breaks)) %>% 
  mutate(treatment = paste0(as.character(wool),
                        as.character(tension)))
```

So just to see what we have:

```
> wb.summary
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   wool [2]
  wool  tension     m    lb    ub treatment 
  <fct> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 A     L        44.6  8.36  80.8 AL   
2 A     M        24    6.68  41.3 AM   
3 A     H        24.6  4.01  45.1 AH   
4 B     L        28.2  8.50  47.9 BL   
5 B     M        28.8  9.92  47.6 BM   
6 B     H        18.8  8.99  28.6 BH
```

First we draw your barplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
g = wb.summary %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = treatment, y = m)) + 
  geom_col()
g
```

[image]

Now we add the error bars

```r
g = g + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lb, ymax = ub)) + 
  ylim(0, 85)
g
```

[image]

Comment: James yours makes sense but what really is tripping me up is the difference between the dataframe graphed in your example and mine.  Mine has 3 columns with the information I am graphing which is how I made 3 bars on my graph.  How do I make sure my ylim and ymax takes all three columns into account?

Comment: @Matt As always there are many ways to do things. One way for you would be to turn your three columns into one stacked column, with a second column indicating which measurement belongs to which variable. E.g. (I have put semi-colons in this because I know the spacing will get screwed up)

`df = data.frame(control = rnorm(10), 
                treat1 = rnorm(10),
                treat2 = rnorm(10));

library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);
df = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = "Treatment",
               values_to = "Values")
`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` package which is having `ggplot2` within it, removes the requirement of `lb` and `ub` calculation like

```
library(tidyverse)

data(ToothGrowth)
head(ToothGrowth)

ToothGrowth %>% mutate(dose = as.factor(dose)) %>% 
  group_by(supp, dose) %>% 
  summarise(new = list(mean_se(len))) %>% 
  unnest(new) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=dose, y=y, fill=supp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

You can use `mean_sdl` in place of `mean_se`for using standard deviation as error bar.